# C - Wrong values in printed array

Tags: c, arrays

I've looked for but nothing helped me. I've deleted even spaces from my code but when I print my array, values are wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    int n, i = 0, j;
    printf("Set number of elements in array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int tab[n];
    printf("Number of elements: %d\n", n);
    printf("Set values for each element: \n");

    while (i < n) {
        printf("Tab[%d] = ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &tab[n]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("There is your array: \n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d\t\t", tab[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

What is happening?

Comment: Use a debugger.  step through the code, watch the variables.  The problem then becomes obvious.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake... Thank you all guys and sorry :D

Comment: We all make mistakes.   I'm a 20 year professional, and still mess up semicolons and quotations.  What separates the noobs from the pros is the ability to self-diagnose with tools like compilers and debuggers.

Comment: @Lawliet , You forgot to accept any answer which solved your issue

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` inside `while` should contain `i` instead of `n`

```
scanf("%d", &tab[i]);
```

and the `printf` inside `for` should contain `j` instead of `0`

```
printf("%d\t\t", tab[j]);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) you are scanning `tab[n]` all the time instead of `tab[i]`.

2) you are printing `tab[0]` all the time instead of `tab[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

You add the item for the nth place in the array. But you should insert it to the ith element

```
while(i<n) {
        printf("Tab[%d] = ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &tab[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

You Also Prints Items From the 0th place. Instead, you should print the jth element.

```
printf("There is your array: \n");
    for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("%d\t\t", tab[j]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You repeatedly read into `tab[n]`.

```
scanf("%d", &tab[n]);
```

In your example, `n == 3`.
So you are repeatedly reading into `tab[3]`.
But you expect all your data to be in `tab[0]`, `tab[1]`, `tab[2]`.

Answer (score -2):

This will print all array values as a string with comma separated values in C#

```
string.Join(", ", myArray.Select(v => v.ToString())
```